# Guessing a secret number to maximize the result

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, algorithms, game-theory

You are given a set $A$ (all elements are different and positive) and
a set $B$ (all elements are different and positive).

Find a optimal number $x$ ( $0 < x \leqslant W$ where $W$ is a given integer ) such that following condition holds :

For example:

$A = \{3, 2, 5\}$

$B = \{1, 6, 3\}$

$A_d = \{1, 2, 3\}$ // this set we have calc. which contains all possible absolute differences of elements of $A$.

Now we are supposed to insert $x$ in $B$ such that the resultant set $B_d$ (formed by differences) have maximum number of same elements as $A_d$.

Given for this case $W=8$ so we can choose $x$ as 7 since $B_d$ set now will be $= \{3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 6\}$ which have all elements as $A_d$.

I hope someone will help me out this is really tricky I left no stones unturned but still not getting it how to do.

Comment: +1 I (also) upvoted, interesting question, very nicely presented.  No elegant avoidance of brute force occurs to me.  One suggestion: although it seems futile to you, you will get a better reaction from mathSE reviewers if you edit your query to include the details of (perhaps) 30 minutes to an hour of the attempts that you have already made.  Even though you know that these attempts (apparently) don't lead to a solution, it is still desired for mathSE queries.

Comment: @user2661923 I did lot of hard work not hour it is hours but it is very difficult to summarize all and most of my trials are not optimal I felt when I did

Comment: Yes, I surmised that from your query.  If it were up to me, I would simply take your word for it.  Then, if I had a solution, (which I don't), I would provide it.  I am merely suggesting that other mathSE reviewers **may** see things differently.  If you can spend about 10-15 minutes editing your query with the details, that should probably work.  If you need help re formatting math (with mathJax), you can consult https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation.

Comment: Note, inserting $x=3$ into $B$ also works, since $6-3=3$ and $3-1=2$ produce the "missing" elements of $A$. (BTW, are you tacitly assuming all elements of $A$ and $B$ are positive *integers*?)

Comment: @BarryCipra ok fine there can be other optimal x also

Comment: Just to be clear, you’re not looking for a brute force solution, right?  Because it’s relatively easy to check all $x$'s whose addition would make $C$ cover at least one more element of $A$ than before.

Comment: Unfortunately such a brute force solution would have a complexity of $\Theta(|A| |B|^2)$.

Comment: I don't see how *game theory* comes into this problem. As the problem is stated, it is not necessary to *guess* anything. The optimum value of $x$ can be found with certainty.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849800/count-squares-of-different-areas-formed-by-intersection-of-lines-parallel-to-x

Comment: @d125q obviously I am not looking for that brute force :) I need best way to do... I tried different ways to do that but still none worked out as a proper algo :((

Comment: @sammygerbil sure I will delete that actually that was original ques. but actual key concept used in that question is what I am asking here can u please tell me how to put that into background context of this question ?? please IDK how to do that

Comment: @solver Ah I see you have deleted the earlier question already. Not sure but I think you still have access to it. If so, go into EDIT for the earlier question (to do that you might have to un-delete it) then COPY everything in the text box. Return to this question, go into EDIT, and PASTE below your current text, giving the new text a sub-heading such as "Background".

Comment: @solver It is good practice to explain your original problem as well as your interpretation in mathematical terms or your method of solution.This is because your interpretation or method might be flawed, or an easier method might exist.